# How to loop the StreamWriter to write the strings from the ChecklistBox

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, loops, streamwriter

Good Day! I need help. I want to loop my StreamWriter to write every string from checkListBox in the notepad and make it as batchfile to execute the SQL Script. 

Situation: 
every checkLISTbox is an SQL, then I need to save it one by one by StreamWriter then execute it on batch file using SQLCMD. yet I need to loop it again. Let's say a matter of 2 or 2.5 seconds *(thats why i use `Thread.Sleep(2000)`)* before run the next batch file containing the another line of the text which is the next checkbox

```
        StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(file_name);
        try
        {   for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (Object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
                {
                    SaveFile.WriteLine(":r \"" + textBox1.Text + "\\" + item + "\"");
                    SaveFile.Close();

                    //Create a batchfile for execution of consolidated script 
                    string execute = "\\Script_Runner.bat";
                    execute = textBox1.Text + execute;
                    StreamWriter SaveFile2 = new StreamWriter(execute);
                    SaveFile2.WriteLine("sqlcmd -S localhost -E -i " + textBox1.Text + "\\" + "test1.sql");
                    SaveFile2.Close();

                    //running the batchfile
                    string ScriptRun = "\\Script_Runner.bat";
                    ScriptRun = textBox1.Text + ScriptRun;
                    Process.Start(ScriptRun);
                }
                this.Refresh();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                i++;

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //error message every script
        }                                              
    }
    catch
    {
    //error message 
    }

    richTextBox2.Text += "\nData Patch Completed.";                  
}
catch (Exception)
{
   // error message upon clicking execute
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you're asking. "I want to loop my stream writer". You *are* looping your stream writer. "Every checkbox is an SQL". No, every checkbox is a checkbox. I think you just need a bit more explanation.

Comment: *I want to verify that it is a checkLISTbox. What didn't you understand?
Maybe u can help. StreamWriter- is the one who writes in the textpad/notepad. Everytime I get my string in Checklistbox is transferred in Notepad and then transferred to be batchfile to execute the Script. I just need to repeat it until the checkLISTbox is finished

Answer (score 1):

since you did not clearly express the need for two loops i consider one as defect.. 
Closing the stream on the first item in the loop may be what you did not want..
i moved Streamwriter-instantiation inside the loop.
maybe it works for you - try.

```
            try
            {   
                    foreach (Object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
                    {
                        StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(file_name);
                        SaveFile.WriteLine(":r \"" + textBox1.Text + "\\" + item + "\"");
                        SaveFile.Close();

                        //Create a batchfile for execution of consolidated script 
                        string execute = "\\Script_Runner.bat";
                        execute = textBox1.Text + execute;
                        StreamWriter SaveFile2 = new StreamWriter(execute);
                        SaveFile2.WriteLine("sqlcmd -S localhost -E -i " + textBox1.Text + "\\" + "test1.sql");
                        SaveFile2.Close();

                        //running the batchfile
                        string ScriptRun = "\\Script_Runner.bat";
                        ScriptRun = textBox1.Text + ScriptRun;
                        Process.Start(ScriptRun);
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                    this.Refresh();
            }
            catch
            {
                //error message every script
            }                                              
        }
        catch
        {
        //error message 
        }                   
                richTextBox2.Text += "\nData Patch Completed.";                  
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       // error message upon clicking execute
```

Comment: Thanks It works, yet It appends the string in the Notepad.
How to send the other strings on the next line? where I will insert it?

Comment: I tried to insert "Environment.NewLine" after the 

"item + "\"" yet it doesnt work

Comment: try 
StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(file_name, true);

Comment: Thanks! :) great help